# Cant resize images on boostrap columns

Tags: html, css, image, resize

So I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS and I'm doing this lesson from CodeAcademy and I'm trying to replicate this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/junction/index.html

The problem is that I'm not being able to make those images in the middle look bigger, they're very small, and I have no idea how to resize them.

Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/eb3roj0j/1/

```
 <!--supporting-->
  <div class="supporting">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://goo.gl/HuNcSi" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <h2>Read</h2>
          <p>Discover new stories and follow your favorite writers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://goo.gl/Vxo5z5" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <h2>Write</h2>
          <p>Create stories about our world, or entirely new worlds.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://goo.gl/93x9GD" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          <h2>Talk</h2>
          <p>Join the conversation by talking with your favorite readers and your fans.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your css you have:

```
.row img
{
    position: relative;

    float: left;

    max-width: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}
```

this is constraining your image size

Comment: i am assuming you are did this to constrain something else on the page. this is a little too broad of a stroke. you should assign whatever element you want to constrain it's own ID or CLASS and then constrain that specifically.

Comment: and don't feel stupid, it's just part of learning.the best thing about your post is that you documented it and created an example for us to help you.

Comment: Yes!  it was the logo on the nav bar, thank you very much for the tips.Much appreciated

Comment: so change ,row img to .logo, and add .logo to your element as a class. you would use a class rather than ID because you would possibly be using that class again on the same page. ID's need to be unique

Comment: Thank you once again, definitely something to keep in mind on my progressing learning.